# What are the differences between XMLHttpRequest and ServletRequest and their responses?

Tags: servlets, xmlhttprequest

I know that XMLHttpRequest and ServletRequest are not different in theory by searching similar questions.

But some details confuse me.

Fox example, if I send an `XMLHttpRequest` to the server, how does the client know the response is for the `XMLHttpRequest` rather than for the `ServletRequest`?

How does the client distinguishes the response type?

Otherwise, on the server side, when I call method:

```
response.getWriter().write(str);
```

Will the argument `str` be present on the browser?

Comment: It's time to learn HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/699710-what-difference-between-xmlhttprequest-standard-http-request) may be of help to you.

> while the standard HTTP request makes a 'synchronous' call and must wait for the response and makes a page-reload (you always get a new html-page to display) a XMLHttpRequest may be used sync (not typical) and async (the better way) without a page-reload. you may ask for the response with javascript and the response is usually xml- or json-data that you may process with js and update parts of your page through the use of dom-methods that manipulate your document ... so you don't need an entire page-reload because all of that is running in the 'background' ...

[This](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/27/is-it-an-ajax-request-or-a-normal-request/) should also help with how the two requests are treated differently by servers and clients.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, @Prmths. And the online content provided by you is very useful for me.